# Robotium: How an .apk app can be re-signed in order to test it with Robotium?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, certificate, robotium

I'm just trying to test an android application using Robotium. The issue I have is that I don't manage to re-sign the application in order to start a test project in Eclipse.
I've followed the tutorial from http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles but with no success.

1. I've generated a .keystore file:
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore myCertificate1.keystore -alias myKey1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
2. Running the jarsigner command:
   jarsigner -verbose -keystore Certificate1.keystore path\appname.apk Key1
3. And I've got an error:
   Certificate chain not found for: Key1.  Key1 must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Could anyone point me in any direction ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be "myKey1" or "Key1"?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot Joachim. It should be "myKey1". Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving your new key an alias `"myKey1"`, but then you're trying to sign with `"Key1"` which (I presume) either does not exist or at the least reference the wrong key.

Comment: I've managed to re-sign the .apk file, but it cannot be installed. I'm getting the following error when trying to run the  "adb install MyApp.apk" command.    Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: Here comes the answer: I was using JDK 1.7.
Now, I'm using JDK 1.6 and everything goes fine.
Thanks for your support.